# Trigger file download in IOS Dolphin browser

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile

I'm trying to trigger file download (.pkpass) in angular mobile app.
Everything works fine in chrome/firefox/opera/safari/Dolphin on android, but not in IOS Dolphin.
I've tried at least 7 different approaches. Please, can anyone help me?

Currently it works (not on ios dolphin) like this: 
window.location.href = configService.host + 'blabla.pkpass';